# How to fix: [splide] A track/list element is missing

Tags: javascript, html, splidejs

im following this [guide](https://splidejs.com/tutorials/thumbnail-carousel/) to create thumbnail carousel but for some reason im getting error.

In the guide they didnt say how to create #main-carousel so i try few different ways but still cant make it work

```
[splide] A track/list element is missing
```

any ideas how to fix this or why this is happen ?

here is my code:

```
    <section id="main-carousel"></section>
    <section id="thumbnail-carousel" class="splide">
      <div class="splide__track">
            <ul class="splide__list">
                <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img1.jpeg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img2.jpeg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img3.jpeg" alt=""></li>
          <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img4.jpeg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.3/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.3/dist/css/splide.min.css">


    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var thumbnails =  new Splide( '#thumbnail-carousel', {
        fixedWidth  : 100,
        fixedHeight : 60,
        gap         : 10,
        rewind      : true,
        pagination  : false,
        isNavigation: true,
        breakpoints : {
          600: {
            fixedWidth : 60,
            fixedHeight: 44,
          },
        },
      } ).mount();
    
      var main = new Splide('#main-carousel', {
      type      : 'fade',
      rewind    : true,
      pagination: false,
      arrows    : false,
    });
    
    main.sync(thumbnails);
    main.mount();
    thumbnails.mount();
    
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after long resurch i found

```
[splide] A track/list element is missing
```

is mean splide__track and splide__list classes are missing for current splide

To fix the issue i should create two identical html splide`s with different IDs

```
     <section id="main-carousel" class="splide">
      <div class="splide__track">
            <ul class="splide__list">
                <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img1.jpeg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img2.jpeg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img3.jpeg" alt=""></li>
          <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img4.jpeg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
     <section id="thumbnail-carousel" class="splide">
       <div class="splide__track">
             <ul class="splide__list">
                 <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img1.jpeg" alt=""></li>
                 <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img2.jpeg" alt=""></li>
                 <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img3.jpeg" alt=""></li>
           <li class="splide__slide"><img src="img4.jpeg" alt=""></li>
             </ul>
       </div>
     </section>
```

P.S. if someone from splide team read this please add additional information how should be created main carousel in this [guide](https://splidejs.com/tutorials/thumbnail-carousel/)

Comment: You are using latest version? https://codepen.io/brandonleetran/pen/bGEKrEE

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, and I resolved it by following the structure outlined in the documentation. For example:

html:

```
<div class="anotherSplide">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
    
      <li class="splide__slide">
        <div> item </div>
      </li>

      <li class="splide__slide">
        <div> item </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Splide('.anotherSplide', {
    // code here
});
```

This did not work for me. Instead, I had to use the following HTML:

```
<div class="splide anotherSplide">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
    
      <li class="splide__slide">
        <div> item </div>
      </li>

      <li class="splide__slide">
        <div> item </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Splide('.splide.anotherSplide', {
    // code here
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Chiming in I also had to add the class `splide` along with my custom class to the parent element. I was able to init splide using only the class, so I think this would work as well `new Splide('.anotherSplide', {`